# When a user inputs x how do you make an x amount of input boxes appear?

Tags: html, input

I can't figure out how to do this in HTML, I'm new so i'd appreciate the help. What I want to do is this: when a user inputs x then an x amount of input boxes should appear(e.g. When they input 2 then 2 input boxes should appear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionalities that you are looking for is possible with `Javascript`. Javascript is the programming language that is responsible for the logic in a web page (and many other places). So, you have to learn JS. But for now...

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {

  let input = document.getElementById('some_id').value;
  let container = document.getElementById('container');
  container.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    let newInput = document.createElement('input');
    container.appendChild(newInput);
  }


});
```

```html
<input id="some_id">

<button id="button">Create Me</button>

<div id="container"></div>
```

You can add the JS code in a separate file or add in at the end of your `body` tag inside a `script` tag

Comment: Thank you!! Is there a way to access one of the inputs in the input boxes that were generated?